# Javascript and PHP (window.open)

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, window.open

So, in my website, I have a news system which has an option to edit and delete the news the administrator desires.

Well, I got the edit part right by using:

`href="noticiaEditarForm.php?id_noticia=<?php echo $id ?>">Editar</a>`

And then a `$_GET` on the other page.

However, this is not how I desire my editing window. 
Therefore, I have been exploring a way to send the PHP variable that contains the primary key for the news table (MySQL) to a popup window, using JavaScript. But that's just the thing, it will only return the 1st value it gets from the query... (i.e If I click to edit the 3rd article, it edits my 1st one. Always.)

Here is my current code:

```
<div class="noticias">
<?php
    include('conn/conn.php');
    mysql_select_db($bd, $conn);

    $resultado = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM noticia INNER JOIN user ON noticia.id_user=user.id_user ORDER BY id_noticia DESC");

    while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)) {
        echo "<h1>" . $linha['titulo'] . "</h1>";
        echo "<i>Posted by " .$linha['username']. " on " . "<y>" . $linha['data'] . "</y>" . "</i>";
        echo "<p>";
        echo $linha['texto'];

        $id = $linha['id_noticia'];

        if (isset($_SESSION['admin'])) {
?>
            <div class="noticiasOpcao">
                <a href="" onClick="open_win_editar()">Editar</a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" href="noticiaApagar.php?id_noticia=<?php echo $id ?>">Apagar</a>
            </div>
<?php
        } 
    }
?>

<script language="javascript">
    function open_win_editar() {
        window.open (
            "noticiaEditarForm.php?id_noticia=<?php echo $id; ?>",
            "Editar notícia",
            "location=1, status=1, scrollbars=1, width=800, height=455"
        );
    }
</script>

<?php mysql_close($conn); ?>

</div>
```

My point is to then use another query to get the title and text of the article to display on an WYSIWYG editor.

Can anyone point out my flaw?

Comment: What is the actual rendered output?  Is the `$id` the same on each iteration of the loop?

Comment: Also, the `window.open` JavaScript call will always have the last `$id` from the PHP loop, since it happens after the loop.  So that function will always open the last one.

Comment: did you try to load the "edit window" directly with correct id? Where is your query that loads the record by id?

Comment: David: I think that's the issue here. He needs to fill out a script block or something to store the possible ID's rather than hardcoding the ID in the open_win_editar function.

Comment: Ricardo, you do not need to edit the title and add "Resolved", just press the accept button next to an answer (like you've already done).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function open_win_editar() {
        window.open ("noticiaEditarForm.php?id_noticia=<?php echo $id; ?>", "Editar notícia", "location=1, status=1, scrollbars=1, width=800, height=455");
     }
</script>
```

Is happening outside of the PHP `while` loop, so the value of `$id` will be the last value that was set to `$id` in the loop.  So the JavaScript code will always open the same link.

If you need the code within the PHP loop to specify the `$id` value for the JavaScript, then you can pass it as an argument to the JavaScript function.  Something like this:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function open_win_editar(targetID) {
        window.open ("noticiaEditarForm.php?id_noticia=" + targetID, "Editar notícia", "location=1, status=1, scrollbars=1, width=800, height=455");
     }
</script>
```

So the code rendering the anchor tags in the loop would pass the argument like this:

```
<a href="" onClick="open_win_editar(<?php echo $id; ?>)">Editar</a>
```

The rendered output would then contain the record-specific `$id` value on each `a` tag to be used by the JavaScript code on the client.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe it was that simple!
Cheers, buddy! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="javascript">
            function open_win_editar() {
                window.open ("noticiaEditarForm.php?id_noticia=<?php echo $id; ?>", "Editar notícia", "location=1, status=1, scrollbars=1, width=800, height=455");
            }
        </script>
```

This is only rendered once, probably with the last ID. You need to figure out a structure so you can pass a different ID to it based on what article you clicked to edit.

Answer (score 0):

The id of the piece to edit is only updated within the while loop and never outside of it.

To use it as you wish you should use a parameter  for the open_with_editar function:

```
<script language="javascript">
            function open_win_editar(id) {
                window.open ("noticiaEditarForm.php?id_noticia="+id, "Editar notícia", "location=1, status=1, scrollbars=1, width=800, height=455");
            }
        </script>
```

Now you only have to update the onclick event and hand over teh respective id:

```
<div class="noticiasOpcao">
      <a href="" onClick="open_win_editar(<?php echo $id; ?>)">Editar</a>
```

That should work.

Regards
STEFAN