# how to show a page that is shown after form data is submitted in a new window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two submit buttons in a form. 
One for creating a post. The other one for previewing a post that's been under editing.

I'd like to show a page that appears after the form data is submitted in a new window when preview button clicked.

For now, I just added jquery code as the below.

```
previewBtn.on('click', function(){
    window.open();
})
```

But, of course, it just shows a blank page in a new window.

I don't know how to show the page that is shown after the form data submitted in a new window.

Please help me out !

Thanks in advance!!!

**+++ edited +++**

I'm sending form data to editdo.php.

In this file, there is a code like this.

```
if(isset($_POST['Post']) && isset($_POST['preview'])){

    Yii::app()->session['preview'] = $_POST['Post'];

    $this->redirect("index.php?r=admin/post/preview");
}
```

Basically, if the form is submitted by clicking a preview button, editdo.php keep the data posted in session and redirect to preview page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript

```
$(".form-btn").click(function(){
   var action = $(this).data("action");
   var form = $(this).parents("form");
   switch(action){
       case "submit":
            form.removeAttr("target");
            form.attr("action","editdo.php");
            break;
       case "preview":
            form.attr("target","_blank");
            form.attr("action","editdo.php?preview=1");
            break;
   }
   form.submit();
});
```

Add target="_blank" to submit in a new window

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['Post']) && $_GET['preview'] == '1'){

    Yii::app()->session['preview'] = $_POST['Post'];

    $this->redirect("index.php?r=admin/post/preview");
}
```

Change to $_GET['preview']

http://jsfiddle.net/Kpd8y/1/

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to show a page in a new window only when the preview button is clicked.

I think if I add target="_blank", even when the post button is clicked, the page after the data is submitted shows in a new window.

Comment: mmm,I got php error "The system is unable to find the requested action "editdo?preview=1"." I'm working on fixing this error.

Comment: this works!

   previewBtn.on('click', function(){
    var form = $(this).parents("form");
             form.attr("target","_blank");
    form.submit();

   })

Answer (score 0):

Use correct syntax: [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open)

```
window.open(urlOfThePage);
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried it. but it didn't work. I added more info to describe my situation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.open(your desired url);
```

Comment: I'd like to submit form data to "index.php?r=admin/post/editdo".
editdo is a php file.

Comment: Im going to add more infomation to describe my situation!!

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249560/javascript-and-php-window-open it will solve your problem i think